# Persistence store options like database for rabbbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq, persistence, messagebroker

We are using rabbit MQ as messaging broker in our project. we gone through some of the blogs and documents about persistence store in Rabbit MQ.

There are default options for the message store like in  memory , queue index and flat files on the disk.

As we are more concern on the message durability , we are searching for best approach for data store with rabbit mq.

Again just to confirm, can we use database like ** for another broker active mq we can use database as persistence store**.

Any help/thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ uses a custom DB and it is not possible to change it as ActiveMQ.

Starting from the version `3.7.0` is possible to change the index DB using `eleveldb`, see:  https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-msg-store-index-eleveldb